# Is it good to add one extra pdf with with summary of a transcript?

Tags: graduate-admissions, transcript-of-records, south-east-asia, bangladesh

In my undergraduate level, I had retaken three courses for grade improvement. I was absent in one exam that's why the grade is showing 'F', since it was improvement exam and I had passing grade in earlier semester, I did not seat for the exam with my little preparation.

I am applying for Ph.D. and I think it might have a negative impact unless they know it's 'F' because of my absence. Is it okay to add one PDF where the title will be summary and there will be a table. On that table, I want to add a column named "comments" with other columns, and I want to add the comment about that exam.

[image: summary of transcript]

Will it be any problem?

Comment: This is not clear to me. Why did you not take the "improvement exam" if not taking it gave you an F?

Comment: My university had AB grade for absent, but I am not sure why they gave me that grade. My university kept changing the grading policy and I was one of the victims of it.

Comment: What country? It would help to get someone who knows this system to answer.

Comment: Bangladesh, but in general do you think adding an extra pdf with the transcript has any negative impact?

Comment: I am intentionally not answering because I don't really understand the situation. I hope someone familiar with that part of the world can answer you.

Comment: It depends. Some universities require you to submit official transcripts, and that transcript with the extra column is by no means the original one. However, it is also possible for you to include supplementary documents in your application. Please check the requirements.

Comment: Does the transcript also show the earlier grade or only the failing grade?

Comment: And are you applying for study in Bangladesh or elsewhere? Especially if it is places with a different marking/grading system?

Comment: I am applying for study in US, currently doing my MS in the USA as well.

Comment: @Buffy, it has both grade, for example D in the regular semester and B+ in the short term/improvement semester.